# git: best way to "stash" changes to continue work from a remote repo

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-remote, git-stash

As far as I understand stashes are local, and are not meant to be pushed to remote repos.

Sometimes I have ongoing work that is not ready to be committed, but that I have to somehow share with other workers or with myself accessing from a different workstation.

What would be the best way to emulate some kind of "remote stash" with git or to use git for a workflow like I've just described?

Comment: Why not use a branch?

Comment: Branching is what you need to do,

Comment: It's worth noting that what `git stash` does is make a commit (well, really, at least two commits, sometimes 3). It's just that the commit that `git stash` makes is on *no* branch, Since it's so much easier to `git push` or `git fetch` commits that *are* on branches, Mureinik's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just use a remote branch. Just make sure that everyone on the team agrees on some naming convention for these "work in progress" branches, and you should be fine. Usually, prefixing a branch with "wip" should convey this message.:

```
$ git push origin wip_new_feature
```

Comment: yes, it sounds good, would you mind posting all the commands?, My guess (I'm NOT a git power user) a `git checkout -b wip_new_feature`, `git add .` `git commit -m 'wip'` and then `git push origin wip_new_feature`... Am I right?

Comment: @opensas yup, that's basically it. Just note it would be more convenient to keep your local and remote branches under the same name (so - `git checkout -b wip_new_feature`) in case you have several such efforts you'd want to keep track of.

Comment: A remote branch will not show the differences in a coherent way like a stash will, it is also messy since instead of preserving straightforwardness and simplicity it seeks to compartmentalize things even further and litter the repo with unnecessary branches to the point you have to assume a separate category of naming conventions for achieving it

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found for something like this is have a synchronized folder like dropbox or onedrive which you share with your other system or coworkers. In that folder you can save patches and then they download them and apply them on the local branch. No commits, No branches, No remote repo.

So once you have the changes you want "remote stashed" do:

```
git add .
git diff --staged > C:/change.patch (the synced folder)
```

Then from the other computer you can just do:

```
git apply C:/change.patch (where your synced folder is located)
```

Comment: What's the motivation for using patches separated from the repository when you all (presumably) already share a repository?

Comment: @Guildenstern simple, multiple people share the repository and I want my changes to be completely private

Comment: They are already private while you are working on the commits locally. Then when you either push them to some cloud drive *or* push them to the shared repository they become public. So this workflow doesn't make the changes *more* private.

Comment: @Guildenstern you control who has access to the cloud drive whereas you don't always have control who has access to the repo